# How to reshape js array to other form?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this array:

```
 [
        {
            "number": 1,
            "detail": detail1,
            "value": [1, 11, 21, 31]
        },
        {
            "number": 2,
            "detail": detail2,
            "value": [2, 12, 22, 32]
        },
        {
            "number": 3,
            "detail": detail3,
            "value": [3, 13, 23, 33]
        }
    ]
```

And I need it in this form:

```
[

    [
     {detail: detail1, value: 1},
     {detail: detail2, value: 2},
     {detail: detail3, value: 3},
    ],
    [
     {detail: detail1, value: 11},
     {detail: detail2, value: 12},
     {detail: detail3, value: 13},
    ],
    [
     {detail: detail1, value: 21},
     {detail: detail2, value: 22},
     {detail: detail3, value: 23},
    ],
    [
     {detail: detail1, value: 31},
     {detail: detail2, value: 32},
     {detail: detail3, value: 33},
    ],
    ...
]
```

How I could do this? Thanks for help

I tried to do it with loop the way shown below, but couldn't get those form:

```
const result = []
for (let i = 0; i < array[0].value.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 1; j < array.length; j++) {
    for (let k = 0; k < array[j].value.length; k++) {
      result.push(values)
    }
  }
}
```

Hope, I provided enough info

EDIT:
I changed question to improve array readability

Comment: Could you put the contents of the image in as text? How do those two data structures relate? (For instance, where is value 9 in the new data structure?)

Comment: Can you please explain the logic to convert the array into desired form?

Comment: Question: The value property is always an array no matter its length? As in, if there's 1 value, it will still be inside an array. right? (talking about the initial array)

Comment: @KyloDev yes, initial array is always array

Comment: @BenStephens i edited question, could you please review?

Comment: I think your initial.... example is better. After you changed to detail and value, quite confusing to me

Comment: In an earlier version of the input array you had one of the value arrays with a shorter length than the others, is that still something that possible?

Comment: @BenStephens yes, that's possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the following help? Please see comments for a little info on what this is doing.

```js
const items = [
  {
    "number": 1,
    "detail": 1,
    "value": [1, 11, 21, 31]
  },
  {
    "number": 2,
    "detail": 2,
    "value": [2, 12, 22, 32]
  },
  {
    "number": 3,
    "detail": 3,
    "value": [3, 13, 23, 33]
  },
  
  // added to show what might happen if there are gaps
  {
    "number": 5,
    "detail": 5,
    "value": [5, 15, 25]
  }
];

// work out the max length of the value arrays
const new_length = Math.max(...items.map((v) => v.value.length));

// create a new array of length new_length and prepopulate with fresh arrays
const result = Array.from({ length: new_length }, () => []);

// for each item create a new entry in the correct result sub array for each
// of the values in the item value array
for(const item of items) {
  for(const index in result) {
    const value = item.value[index];
    
    if(value)
      result[index][item.number - 1] = { detail: item.detail, value };
  }
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I wanted. As your answer is more detailed, I'll accept it

Answer (score 0):

```js
const starting_arr = [{
    "number": 1,
    "detail": 4,
    "value": [5, 6, 9]
  },
  {
    "number": 2,
    "detail": 5,
    "value": [7, 8]
  },
  {
    "number": 3,
    "detail": 6,
    "value": [13, 14, 15]
  }
];

function ArrayExpand(arr) {
  const output_arr = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    output_arr.push([]);

    const {
      number,
      detail,
      value
    } = arr[i]; // destructuring the object

    for (let j = 0; j < value.length; j++) {
      output_arr[i].push({
        number,
        detail,
        value: value[j]
      })
    }
  }
  
  return output_arr
}

console.log(ArrayExpand(starting_arr))
```

this should do it.

We initialize an output array where we will be pushing the expanded forms of the individual objects.

At each 'i' object, I'm pushing an empty array to the output array. Then at each 'j' element in value, I'm pushing the new expanded object to the empty array.

Comment: each array inside output_array should contain three objects, because we have three different details(detail1, detail2, detail3) and this objects should contain 'value'. those "value"-s are uniqe in each array, e.g: if in first array in object where "detail" value equals "detail1" and 'value' equals "value1", in second array in object where detail equals "detail1" value can't be "value1"

Answer (score 0):

You can use map and foreach with descructuring to transform your data:

```js
const inputArray = [
{
    "number": 1,
    "detail": 1,
    "value": [1, 11, 21, 31]
},
{
    "number": 2,
    "detail": 2,
    "value": [2, 12, 22, 32]
},
{
    "number": 3,
    "detail": 3,
    "value": [3, 13, 23, 33]
}
];

const result = inputArray[0].value.map((_, idx) => {
    const values = [];
    inputArray.forEach(({ detail, value }) => {
        values.push({ detail, value: value[idx] });
    });
    return values;
});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I wanted. Thank you very much. Thanks to others too, who tried to help

Answer (score -1):

```js
const d = [

    [
        { detail: "detail1", value: "value1" },
        { detail: "detail2", value: "value2" },
        { detail: "detail3", value: "value3" },
    ],
    [
        { detail: "detail1", value: "value11" },
        { detail: "detail2", value: "value12" },
        { detail: "detail3", value: "value13" },
    ],
    [
        { detail: "detail1", value: "value21" },
        { detail: "detail2", value: "value22" },
        { detail: "detail3", value: "value23" },
    ],
    [
        { detail: "detail1", value: "value31" },
        { detail: "detail2", value: "value32" },
        { detail: "detail3", value: "value33" },
    ],
]

const x = [
    {
        "number": 1,
        "detail": "detail1",
        "value": ["value1", "value11", "value21", "value31"]
    },
    {
        "number": 2,
        "detail": "detail2",
        "value": ["value2", "value12", "value22", "value32"]
    },
    {
        "number": 3,
        "detail": "detail3",
        "value": ["value3", "value13", "value23", "value33"]
    }
]

let desired = []

for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    let a = [];
    for (let j = 0; j < x.length; j++) {
        a.push({
            detail: x[j].detail,
            value: x[j].value[i]
        })
    }
    desired.push(a);
}
console.log('desired: ', desired);
```

Comment: this won't work if the number of elements in the value arrays are different in each array. You'll have to fix that